# Find this limit without using L'Hopital's rule or Taylor Series

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I want to solve $$\lim_{x\to 1^{-}}{\frac{\sqrt[4]{\cos{\frac{\pi x}{2}}}}{\arccos(\frac{2}{\pi}\arcsin(x))}}$$
**without** using differentiation in any context. Basically without using L'Hopital's rule and Taylor's theorem.

I have managed to simplify it somehow by substituting $x = -\frac{2}{\pi}y +1$:
$$\lim_{x\to 1^{-}}{\frac{\sqrt[4]{\cos{\frac{\pi x}{2}}}}{\arccos(\frac{2}{\pi}\arcsin(x))}} = $$
$$\lim_{y\to 0^{+}}{\frac{\sqrt[4]{\sin{y}}}{\arccos(\frac{2}{\pi}\arcsin(-\frac{2}{\pi}y +1))}}=$$
$$\lim_{y\to 0^{+}}{\frac{\sqrt[4]{\sin{y}}}{\sqrt[4]{y}}}\lim_{y\to 0^{+}}{\frac{\sqrt[4]{y}}{\arccos(\frac{2}{\pi}\arcsin(-\frac{2}{\pi}y +1))}} =$$
$$1 \lim_{y\to 0^{+}}{\frac{\sqrt[4]{y}}{\arccos(\frac{2}{\pi}\arcsin(-\frac{2}{\pi}y +1))}}$$

However I am having trouble simplifying further.

**I am allowed to use the following facts**:
$$\sin{x} = x + o(x), \quad x \to 0$$
$$\tan{x} = x + o(x), \quad x \to 0$$
$$\arcsin{x} = x + o(x), \quad x \to 0$$
$$\arctan{x} = x + o(x), \quad x \to 0$$
$$\ln{(1+x)} = x + o(x), \quad x \to 0$$
$$\cos{x} = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + o(x^2), \quad x \to 0$$
$$a^x = 1+ x\ln{a} + o(x), \quad x \to 0$$
$$(1+x)^a = 1 + ax + o(x), \quad x \to 0$$
$$\cos{x}\sim 1, \quad x \to 0$$
$$if \quad \lim_{x \to a}{g(x) \ln{f(x)}} = A \quad then, \ \lim_{x \to a}{(f(x))^{g(x)}} = 
\begin{cases}
e^A \ &if \ A \in R \\
\infty  \ &if \ A = \infty \\ 
0  \ &if \ A = -\infty
\end{cases}
$$

Any hints or help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: If you use "\arccos", "\arcsin" and "\arctan" your post will look nicer

Comment: will do, thanks!

Comment: I think the correct notation is $\sin x = x + o(x^2)$, $\cos x = 1-\frac{x^2}{2} + o(x^3)$ etc.

Comment: @AdamLatosiński Since I am using little o, from Taylors theorem: f(x-a) = ... + (etc)*(x-a)^k + o((x-a)^k). If I was using big O, f(x-a) = ... + (etc)*(x-a)^k + O((x-a)^{k+1}). Therefore ie, sinx = x^1 + o(x^1). However this is only my understanding, I am not certain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $$ \cos x = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + O(x^4) \qquad \text{for }x\to 0 $$
we can conclude
$$ x = \arccos\Big(1-\frac{x^2}{2} + O(x^4)\Big) \qquad \text{for }x\to 0  $$
$$ \sqrt{2t} = \arccos\Big(1-t + O(t^2)\Big) \qquad \text{for }t\to 0^+  $$
$$ \arccos(1-t) = \sqrt{2t\big(1 + O(t)\big)} \qquad \text{for }t\to 0^+  $$
$$ \arccos(y) = \sqrt{2(1-y)\big(1 + O(1-y)\big)} \qquad \text{for }y\to 1^-  $$
$$ \arccos(y) = \sqrt{2(1-y)} +  O\big((1-y)^\frac32\big)  \qquad \text{for }y\to 1^-  $$
Since $$\arcsin x = \frac{\pi}{2}-\arccos x $$ we have
$$ \arcsin(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} - \sqrt{2(1-x)} +  O\big((1-x)^\frac32\big)  \qquad \text{for }x\to 1^-  $$
$$ \frac{2}{\pi}\arcsin(x) = 1 - \frac{2}{\pi}\sqrt{2(1-x)} +  O\big((1-x)^\frac32\big)  \qquad \text{for }x\to 1^-  $$
\begin{align} \arccos \big(\frac{2}{\pi}\arcsin(x)\big) &= \arccos\Big(1 - \frac{2}{\pi}\sqrt{2(1-x)} +  O\big((1-x)^\frac32\big) \Big) = \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{4}{\pi}\sqrt{2(1-x)} + O\big((1-x)^\frac32\big)} + O\big((1-x)^\frac34\big) = \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{4\sqrt{2}}{\pi}} (1-x)^\frac14 +  O\big((1-x)^\frac34\big)  \qquad \text{for }x\to 1^- \end{align}
Similarily, because $$ \cos(x) = \sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)$$
we have
$$ \cos(x) = (\frac{\pi}{2}-x) + O\big((\frac{\pi}{2}-x)^3\big) \qquad \text{for } x\to \frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$ \cos(\frac{\pi x}{2}) = \frac{\pi}{2}(1-x) + O\big((1-x)^3\big) \qquad \text{for } x\to 1$$
\begin{align} \sqrt[4]{\cos(\frac{\pi x}{2})} &= \sqrt[4]{\frac{\pi}{2}(1-x) + O\big((1-x)^3\big)}\\
&= \sqrt[4]{\frac{\pi}{2}(1-x)} \sqrt[4]{1+O\big((1-x)^2\big)} =\\
&= \sqrt[4]{\frac{\pi}{2}} (1-x)^\frac14 + O\big((1-x)^\frac94\big) \qquad \text{for } x\to 1^- \end{align}
In total, we have
\begin{align} \frac{\sqrt[4]{\cos(\frac{\pi x}{2})}}{\arccos \big(\frac{2}{\pi}\arcsin(x)\big)} &= \frac{\sqrt[4]{\frac{\pi}{2}} (1-x)^\frac14 + O\big((1-x)^\frac94\big)}{\sqrt{\frac{4\sqrt{2}}{\pi}} (1-x)^\frac14 +  O\big((1-x)^\frac34\big)} = \\
&= \frac{\pi^\frac34}{2\sqrt{2}} + O\big((1-x)^\frac12\big)\end{align}

Comment: Shouldn't the first row be O(x^3) by default? I have been trying to figure this out but to no avail.

Comment: By default it should be $U(x^3)$, but since $\cos x = \cos (-x)$ it can be shown that it's actually $O(x^4)$.

Comment: Where can I find more information about U(x^3), I dont seem to be able to find any articles relating to it. What is it called?

Comment: Tthat was a typo, I meant $O(x^3)$.